# ZSH and completion of files with newline characters

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I am experimenting with ZSH on nasty file names, especially file names with the newline character in it.

Here is how I create them:

```
$ touch "filename<hit return here>
1"

$ touch "filename<hit return here>
2"
```

Now I want to copy it:

```
$ cp filename<tab>
```

ZSH completes with:

```
$ cp filename$'\n'
```

and refuses to give me the option for 1 or 2.

What's happening here ?

Comment: Even with `zsh -f`? What version? No pb here with 5.0.2

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I'm using zsh 5.0.0. Yes, zsh -f solves the problem. Why ?

Comment: There's a setting in you `~/.zshrc` that causes it to break.

Comment: It's not working, even with an empty ~/.zshrc. But it's working with zsh -f.

Comment: Then it may be a setting in `/etc/zshrc` or some other initialization file. Unfortunately some completion settings can make completion of special characters fail in odd ways.